# Jersey RESTful Services: Resources & Responses

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I see a lot of Jersey-based web services consisting of 1+ [`WebResources`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html) that have 1+ endpoints/methods like so:

```
package com.myws.fizz;
public class FizzResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/fizz/{id}")
    public Response getFizzById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // ...etc.
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/fizz")
    public Fizz getFizzByFoo(Foo foo) {
        // ...etc.
    }
}

package com.myws.buzz;
public class BuzzResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/buzz")
    public Response createBuzz(Buzz buzz) {
        // ...etc.
    }
}
```

- I'm confused with what Jersey considers a "resource". Is there a relationship between a "resource" and a database? A table? A POJO?
- When do you return a `Response` vs. a POJO? Look at my 2 `getFizz` methods above. When do I return a `Fizz` and when do I return a `Response`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term *"Resource"* isn't so much just a Jersey term, as it is a REST term. When dealing with REST, we have **Resources** and **Representations**. A resource can be anything, and in this context, it is some object located on the server, with a URL location. When a client requests for a resource, we send back a representation of it. You ask:

> Is there a relationship between a "resource" and a database? A table? A POJO?

It *could* be a database (that's a thing). And we could simply represent it as a JSON object with the name of the database. Also it *could* be a table (that's a thing). And we could represent it as a JSON object with the name and column names. It *could* be a row in a table, and we could represent that with a JSON object with the column names as the keys and the row values as the JSON values. It could be a web page, an image, whatever. So hopefully you get the point that a resource can be *anything*. What we send back is its representation.

But the term resource is not just limited to returning something to a client request. The client could also *send* us a representation of a resource, to say create a new resource (POST) or change an existing resource (PUT). The client may send us a JSON representation of a row (resource) in our database.

> When do you return a `Response` vs. a POJO? Look at my 2 `getFizz` methods above. When do I return a `Fizz` and when do I return a `Response`?

Returning `Response` allows you to fine tune the `Response`. When the client make a request, they always get back a response. Responses have headers, and entity bodies. When the return type of the resource method is `Fizz`, you are saying the entity body type will be a `Fizz` type. When the method returns, what actually happens is that the `Fizz` object *isn't* directly returned to the requesting client, all by itself. Behind the scenes, it gets wrapped in a `Response` that get's sent back to the client. The framework will set the headers it feels appropriate.

So whether we decide to return a `Response` or `Fizz`, it will get wrapped in a `Response`. And like I said, when we return a `Response`, it allows us to fine tune the `Response`, adding our own headers, status codes and such. For example, say someone make a `POST`. You could do something like

```
@POST
@Path("/buzz")
@Produces(...)
public Response createBuzz(Buzz buzz, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    int buzzID = // create buzz and get the resource id
    UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
    builder.path(Integer.toString(buzzId));  // concatenate the id.
    return Response.created(builder.build()).build();
}
```

Basically what this does is create the resource, say in the database, and we get a return id. We can use the id to concatenate to the URI to the id, this will be the new resource location. In terms of the `Response`, `.created(...)` is saying that the [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) should be `201 Created`, and the value we pass to the `created` method is the location of the newly created resource. This location will be set as the `Location` header in the response. So lets say that the path to the POST request is `http://blah.com/buzz`. What we would send back is `http://blah.com/buzz/100`, where `100` is the `buzzId`, and this complete URL is how we will access the buzz resource say with a GET requesst to a resource method annotated with say `@GET @PATH("/buzz/{id}")`

In terms of a `GET`, with a `Response`, we could do

```
Fizz newFizz = fizzService.getFizz();
return Response.ok(newFizz).build();  // sends the Fizz as the entity body
```

This is really not so much different than just returning the `newFizz` from the method, because we aren't doing anything special with the `Response`. We're just saying the status code should be `200 OK` and attaching the entity body. This is what normally happens with a successful GET request. So if we just return the `Fizz`, instead of a `Response`, in the case of a successful GET, the framework will implicitly attach a 200 OK status.

Personally, I prefer to return `Responses`, because of the fine tuning factor.

Comment: what will be returned in case of unsuccessful GET with return type of POJO?