# In REST / Java, what should I return if my object is null?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a simple POJO that I annotated with REST annotations as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("/domains/{domainid}")
@Override
public Domain getDomain(@PathParam("domainid") UUID domainID) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Retrieving domain "+ domainID);
    Domain d = null;
    try {
        d = MyClient.getDomains().get(domainID.toString());
        logger.debug("Returning "+d.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Could not retrieve domain", e);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Note that the log statement including `d.getName()` can actually throw an NPE which is then caught and logged. That's not pretty but it's also not the point here.

Ultimately whether `d` has a value or not, I return it.

In the case of a `null` value, my client receives an HTTP 204 status code. This is what `wget` displays: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204 No Content`

Oddly enough, my browsers don't budge an inch. They still display the previous page (I suppose it makes sense to stay put when no content is received). I would have expected a blank page.

Three questions:

- is HTTP 204 the right response to be returned?
- how can I control that via annotations? Via other configuration?
- what is the standard REST best practice regarding null objects?

Thanks

#### EDIT

There is a great question on the very same topic here: [Is it correct to return 404 when a REST resource is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845631/is-it-correct-to-return-404-when-a-rest-resource-is-not-found/26845991#26845991)

Comment: I asked the same question yesterday. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845631/is-it-correct-to-return-404-when-a-rest-resource-is-not-found .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the request is trying to GET/locate/find a resource, and it can't be found, traditionally, we should send a 404 Not Found. For further discussion [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26845991/2587435).

That being said, I generally like to have my resource methods return `Response`, as it's easier to fine tune the response the way I want (a little - not much - more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26666497/2587435)). But seeing as how your method is overriding an interface contract (and returning a model object), JAX-RS gives us a nice hierarchy of exceptions that will get mapped to a particular response/status. The list can be [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26798284/2587435).

So in your particular case, if the resource can't be found, you can throw a `WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)` or a `NotFoundException`, and the exception will be mapped to a 404 Not Found. Something like

```
d = MyClient.getDomains().get(domainID.toString());
if (d == null) {
    throw new NotFoundException();  // <-- JAX-RS 2.0
    // or throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
                                    // ^^  JAX-RS 1.x 
}
```

The method will exit when the exception is thrown, and the client will receive a response with a 404 Not Found status.

---

**Related Q&As**

- [How to catch 404 (NotFoundException) without being dependant on a JAX-RS implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26915595/2587435)
- [Is it correct to return 404 when a REST resource is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26845631/2587435)

---

**EDIT**

In the first line I stated *"If the request is trying to GET/locate/find a resource.."*, but really, this applies to almost all cases we are using [URI templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Template), whether it is for a GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, whatever. Consider this example

```
@PUT
@Path("/customers/{id}")
public Response updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") long id, Customer customer) {
    ...
}
```

Here is a method that allows the client to update a customer via a PUT. The client should know the complete URI to the resource before trying to update it. If the `{id}` parameter (used for lookup) is not found say in a database, then the resource doesn't exist, and a 404 Not Found should also be returned to the client.

Comment: I am tempted to say that using NotFoundException() would tie my implementation to REST but then again using annotations also does that, right?

Comment: If you don't want to throw one of these JAX-RS exceptions, you can write a `ContainerResponseFilter` and just throw an exception in the filter, or explicitly set the status. But then again, like you said, the JAX-RS annotations already ties you in