# How to catch 404 (NotFoundException) without being depndant on a JAX-RS implemenation?

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs

Typically one uses `ExceptionMapper` to catch exceptions, log them, return a customized error messages.

However while JAX-RS provides an `NotFoundException` in its api, the implementations (Jeresy, CXF,...) provide their own NotFoundException (such as `com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException`) which doesn't extends the JAX-RS one.

Leaving us with the sole option of having in our code implementation specific imports.
This makes it hard if one wants to switch implementations.

Is there another way to do this, to avoid the dependency on a specific implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is there another way to do this, to avoid the dependency on a specific implementation?"

Use a newer vendor version, that supports JAX-RS 2.0.

The [WebApplicationException Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26798284/2587435) (i.e. `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException` included) wasn't introduced until 2.0, though the [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) itself has existed since 1.0. That being said, below are the vendors and versions that started using JAX-RS 2.0

- Resteasy 3.0.0
- Jersey (RI) 2.0
- CXF 2.7 (not full 2.0 - but close - full is in 3.0)

For prior releases, we could just use the `WebApplicationException` to wrap a response/status, like 
`throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)`. You could then map this exception to the mapper, and `getResponse().getStatus()` from the exception if you needed to check the response status.

Any JAX-RS related exception, *not* thrown by us will also get wrapped in a `WebApplicationException`, so just having the mapper map to `WebApplicationException` should allow us to do what we need. A bit of a hassle to do all the checks.

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer is to use `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException`

in your `ExceptionMapper` you can add

```
if (e instanceof WebApplicationException) // add this towards the end of the ExceptionMapper since it is a general exception
{
         // you can use the following for log or exception handling
        int status = ((WebApplicationException) e).getResponse().getStatus();
        if (status ==Response.Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode())
        {
            //deal with 404
        }
        else
        {
          // deal with other http codes
        }

}
```